# Problems with random "Lists"

Tags: python

I want to create a game where a person is drawn out randomly.
Can some1 check the code if everything is setup correctly.
I have tested the code numerous times and its ok in my eyes.
But when I send the code to a review, to an online class I only get 50% score.

```
import random

#  Don't change the code below 
test_seed = int(input("Create a seed number: "))
random.seed(test_seed)

# Split string method
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")
names = names_string.split(", ")
#  Don't change the code above 

#Write your code below this line 
print(names)

names_count = len(names)

random_name_number = random.randint(0, names_count)
print(f"{names[random_name_number]} is going to buy the meal today!")
```

Comment: You should check `random.choice`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is almost certainly with `randint`.  Unlike most Python conventions, the parameters to `randint` are inclusive.  That means, if you supply `(0,10)`, you are going to get numbers from 0 to 10.  In your case, if they supply 10 names, using index 10 is going to cause an exception.

You want `random.randrange`, not `random.randint`.  `randrange(0,10)` will supply numbers from 0 to 9.

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thank you very much!
Thats going into my notepad :)

Comment: Totally forgot we start counting with 0.
So I could also make -> names_count = len(names) -1
And still use the randint.